# YII2 Kartik - ExportMenu Export data with checked item only

Tags: javascript, php, plugins, yii2, export

I include Kartik yii2 ExportMenu plugin and its working fine for all data export but now I want to export only selected rows which is checked on grid.

```
<?php 
  $gridColumns = [
      ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
      'username',
      'email',
      [
         'label' => Yii::t('app','User Access'),
         'value' => function($model){ 
              if($model->access_level == 1) { return 'Read/Write/Import/Export'; }
              if($model->access_level == 2) { return 'Read/Write'; }
              if($model->access_level == 3) { return 'Read'; }
            }
      ],
      'fullname',
      // [
      //    'label' => Yii::t('app','Status'),
      //    'value' => function($model){ 
      //         if($model->status == 10) { return 'Active'; }
      //         if($model->status == 0) { return 'Inactive'; }
      //       }
      // ],
      [
     'attribute' => 'created_at',
     'format' => ['date' , 'php:d/m/Y'],
     'label' => Yii::t('app','Created On'),
     'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'width:12%;'],
      ],
      [
         'attribute' => 'updated_at',
         'format' => ['date' , 'php:d/m/Y'],
         'label' => Yii::t('app','Modified On'),
         'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'width:12%;'],
      ],
      // 'updated_by',
      [
         'attribute' => 'updated_by',
         'label' => Yii::t('app','Modified By'),
         'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'width:12%;'],
        'value' => 'user.username',
        //  'value' => function($model){ 
        //       return $model->user->username;
        // }
      ],

      // ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
  ]; 
      echo ExportMenu::widget([
               'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
               'columns' => $gridColumns,
               'target' => ExportMenu::TARGET_BLANK,
               'showConfirmAlert' => false,
               'filename' => 'Users',
               'dropdownOptions' => [
                'label' => 'Export',
                'class' => 'btn btn-info', 
                'export' => true,
                'toolbar'=>[
                '{export}',
                '{toggleData}'
                ]          
              ],
               'exportConfig'=>[
               ExportMenu::FORMAT_HTML=>false,
               ExportMenu::FORMAT_TEXT=>false,
               ExportMenu::FORMAT_PDF=>false,
               ExportMenu::FORMAT_EXCEL=>false,
               ],
          ]);?>
```

Can anyone please help me to export data which is checked only .
If you need any other information related code please ask.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a column to your columns onfiguration with this param:

```
[
    'class' => 'kartik\grid\CheckboxColumn',
    'headerOptions' => ['class' => 'kartik-sheet-style'],
],
```

And after you need to write your own code that will filter the data provider to return only selected rows in export menu. So your grid view data provider and export menu data provider will become different and you need to control the export menu data provider via the selected rows of grid view.

For get selected rows of GriView in JS you can to this:

```
var keys = $('#grid').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
// keys is an array consisting of the keys associated with the selected rows
```

For more info visit: [Data widgets Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#checkbox-column)